# Get value from one click event to other event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code written by other like this.

```
<button onclick="javascript:confirm("Are you sure?");" id="confirm_button"/>
```

Now, to add more functionality to this button I am attaching one click event to the same button

```
$("#confirm_button").live("click",function(event){

//Need value from the confirm box.
//code goes here.
});
```

How to get the value from the first event in the event listener? I need if for my code to work.
The one way is that I have to move this confirm box into my click event listener, But requirements don't allow me.
Thanks

Comment: Hi what does it mean "requirements don't allow me".? you can move the confirm box to jquery click event.

Comment: These buttons are created by if else loops(PHP), so I just can't move that confirm box.

Comment: that will not affect to your stuff because whenever condition is met and you click on the button only at that time your jquery click event fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a global variable and the store value ion that,so it can be used in other functions

somewhat like this

```
<script>
//global variable here
var testvariable;

function1
{
//initalize value here
}

function2
{
//use here
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$("#confirm_button").live("click",function(event){

    var isvalid = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if(isvalid){

    // to get the value of your selector.
    }
    else
    {
    // do something else
   }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Global Scope variables` might help you with your problem. If a `variable` is declared  outside a `function`, then that `variable` exists on the `global object`.

Check this link.you will get an pretty lot of information about the various `scopes`.. :)

```
<script>
      var globalVariable=  "someValue";//Use this variable anywhere u may need..
</script>
```

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/

Answer (score 0):

Use confirm inside jquery Something like this:

```
$("#confirm_button").live("click",function(event){

    var valid = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if(valid){
        //do something
        var myVal = $("YOUR SELECTOR").val(); // to get the value of your selector.
    }else{
        // do something else
    }    
});
```

Comment: I know this is the way to achieve it. I don't want to move confirm box. anyway thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" onclick="var tmp=confirm('Are you sure?');if(tmp) foo(); "  
 id="confirm_button" value="btn"/>

//and in javascript function write ur code
function foo()
{
alert('add functions');
}
```

Comment: I guess I can't have jQuery event handler. anyway this suits my requirement.